# Sonarqube Xpath rule to check SSIS packages with extension .dtsx

Tags: ssis, sonarqube

I have a requirment to validate Informatica and SSIS packages (XML) using rules written in SonarQube. The rules are activated with Quality Profile for XML language.

For informatica, the workflow exports are in below naming formation and it is working fine.

```
wf_test.xml
```

But for SSIS, the default extension of Package XML file is .dtsx and the rules are not validating those files.

```
package_test.dtsx
```

Is there any way to run the rules against SSIS packages without changing the extension to XML. If I rename the extension to .xml it is working.

Answer (score 1):

You can set it up in configuration.

Under administration -> Configuration -> XML you can set up file extensions being analyzed by xml plugin.[image: SQ XML plugin configuration]

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I do not have administration access, anyway I'll check with the admin team and let you know if it worked. I will mark tthe answer correct after it :)

Comment: If you had permissions to manage your project on the server, you could change it only for your project (`Project → Administration → General Settings → XML`).

Comment: I am not sure at the moment, but it could be posible on command line with -Dsonar.xml.file.suffixes=dtsx